# Oracle database size query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using express edition and want to get database size for the same.
Is the query right?

```
select a.data_size+b.temp_size+c.redo_size "total_size"
from ( select sum(bytes) data_size
         from dba_data_files ) a,
     ( select nvl(sum(bytes),0) temp_size
         from dba_temp_files ) b,
     ( select sum(bytes) redo_size
         from sys.v_$log ) c
```

Comment: In my XE it returns 4GB so it appears to report the *allocated* space (rather than the space actually *used*, which is half that size in my case). Is that the figure you're after?